# Javascript Kubernetes Client: List and Read Custom Resource Definition

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I'm using the [Javascript Kubernetes Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) and I'm trying to read all resources from a custom resource definition. In particular I want to run `kubectl get prometheusrule` (prometheusrule is my CRD).

I couldn't find a wat to do this yet. I can read resources like this:

```
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespacedPod('default').then((res) => {
    res.body.items.forEach(pod => console.log(pod.metadata.name));
});
```

But it does not provide a method for reading CRDs.

I also tried

```
const k8Client = k8s.KubernetesObjectApi.makeApiClient(kc);
k8Client.read({ kind: "service"}).then(res => console.log(res));
```

But this way I get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unrecognized API version and kind: v1 service`

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [listNamespacedCustomObject](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/gen/api/customObjectsApi.ts#L1491) function. This function has four required arguments as described below:

- **group** - the custom resource's group name
- **version** - the custom resource's version
- **namespace** - the custom resource's namespace
- **plural** - the custom resource's plural name.

---

I've created a sample script that lists all `PrometheusRules` to illustrate how it works:

```
$ cat list_rules.js
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node')
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig()
kc.loadFromDefault()

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CustomObjectsApi)

k8sApi.listNamespacedCustomObject('monitoring.coreos.com','v1','default', 'prometheusrules').then((res) => {
    res.body.items.forEach(rule => console.log(rule.metadata.name));
});
```

We can check if it works as expected:

```
$ node list_rules.js
prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager.rules
prometheus-kube-prometheus-etcd
prometheus-kube-prometheus-general.rules
prometheus-kube-prometheus-k8s.rules
...
```

Comment: Do you know it there is a way to get all custom objects? Or would I need to call `listNamespacedCustomObject` and then for each object call `getNamespacedCustomObject`?

Comment: I've inspected the [customObjectsApi.ts](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/gen/api/customObjectsApi.ts) and I'm not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: this seems like you need to know a lot of info that isn't needed with `kubectl`. For example `k get PrometheusRule` would work... is there another API that acts the same way or is `kubectl` doing stuff behind the scenes to figure out all these details?